# I have installed debian 10 xfce and have problems with network manager applet/template in 'panel'

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, xfce

I have recently install Debian 10 "buster" xfce. I am now facing issues with the network manager applet in the panel.

The problem is that it does not detect and show the current means of internet(like ethernet or wifi or usb tethering) and its speed. Although internet works fine and all the options work fine like choosing wifi hotspots and enabling or disabling wired/wireless networks, etc.

The applet is same as system monitor applet but does not work.

However, when I manually entered the 'name' of[image] the current means of internet (usb tethering) it works immediately.
Hence, i want this to be automatic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a Network Monitor to monitor the network traffic.

The network manager applet `nm-applet` is provided by `network-manager-gnome`  package:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome
```

From the terminal:

```
nm-applet &
```

After installing `network-manager-gnome` , you will be able to add the network manager applet to your panel.

Comment: this does nothing

Answer (score 1):

install nm-tray - simple NetworkManager front end.

```
sudo apt install nm-tray
```

Answer (score 0):

as add to @GAD3R for **centos 8** The network manager applet **nm-applet** is provided by **network-manager-applet**

```
yum install network-manager-applet
```